# How to access variable inside another function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a function to calculate the screen width

```
var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();

function checkScreenSize()
{   
    screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();
}

jQuery(window).on("resize", checkScreenSize).resize();
```

How can I use this screenWidth inside another function?

**EDIT:**

I want to access this variable here, for example:

```
function showContent() {
    if(screenWidth <= 1000)
    {
         console.log(screenWidth);
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you try to access it and its not available?

Comment: I think what @Deep wanted to know is, where do you define this function at where do you call it. If it is called before the checkScreenSize Method has completed then, the variable has not been set with the `width` value. Do you call it every time a resize event happens? How do you synchronize the two methods? If `schowContent` is defined outside of the scope where the `var screenWith` variable (which is not nessecarily a "global" variable; you could have defined it in another function body or in a requirejs module) is defined then, the `screenWith` will be unknown to the `showContent` Method.

Answer (score 1):

Since `screenWidth` is a global variable declared outside the `function` you have mentioned, you can access it as it is:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(screenWidth);
}
```

Comment: I should have said that I need the screen width to update when the window is size also

Comment: @KeithDonegan your global variable is accessible from anywhere. If you need to update it on different actions, then you need to add handlers for that purpose. You already have a resize handler. How is this not working and what do you want to achieve instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your global `screenWidth`is quite useless...

if you need to know the width inside the resize handler callback that's where you need to call `jQuery(window).width()`

```js
function checkScreenSize(){
  var w = $(window).width()
  console.log(w)
}

jQuery(window).on("resize", checkScreenSize)

// .resize() is a shorthand for .on('resize' method
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you defined variable out of function , it will be global variable and you can use it in other function !! 

do you have problme with this ?

---

you can also visit : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by defining said variable in `global` scope; if that `var screenWidth = ...` is defined inside some other function context you will not have access to it from other functions.

Using **globals** is a bad idea; however, in many cases you need some variable value that you need access to from other places. In this case, you could construct a well defined "Globals" container, like i.e:

```
'use strict';        // strict mode    :: prevents nasty bugs
this.Main = this;    // super-global   :: refers `window` -or- `global`

Main.Globals = {screenWidth:null};

// your dynamic screen resizing code here sets the `Globals.screenWidth`
// now you have access to this anywhere
```

You can also write some code to have this `Globals` object be only writable by certain functions, but this technique is probably out of the scope of this question; however it could be a good idea considering that this code is part of a large project with many collaborators in your team.

Comment: If you need a more elaborate answer that includes dynamically setting the values upon window resize event; or even if I should add the write restrictions code - just pop a comment here and I'll add it ;)